# Implicit currying in Scheme with syntax-rules?

Tags: macros, functional-programming, scheme, currying, syntax-rules

Jeffrey  Meunier has an implicit Curry macro [here](http://www.engr.uconn.edu/~jeffm/Papers/curry.html), which uses defmacro. I was wondering if someone has ever written this with syntax-rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of curry implementations for Scheme -- none can be as elegant as Haskell, since there functions are always unary functions, so everything can be curried.  (But this can of course be implemented in a sufficiently powerful Scheme like [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/).)

As for the macro that you've dug up -- it's a pretty bad one: not only does it use an unhygienic macro, it's also calling `eval` explicitly, and relies on an implementation of environments etc.  But it's easy to do that with a simple `syntax-rules` macro.  AFAICT, this is what it implements:

```
(define-syntax-rule (clambda (x ... . r) b ...)
  (let ([len  (length '(x ...))] [real (lambda (x ... . r) b ...)])
    (let loop ([argss '()] [n 0])
      (lambda args
        (let ([n (+ n (length args))] [argss (cons args argss)])
          (if (>= n len)
            (apply real (apply append (reverse argss)))
            (loop argss n)))))))
```

But there's an important note here.  The page that you reference says that an problem of the function version is that it's explicit -- but it also has an important advantage: with the macro implementation you must define a function using `clambda`, whereas the functional version can be used with any built in function.  In many Scheme implementations there are facilities to inspect a function's arity, and using this it's possible to implement a currying function version that knows when to call the original function.